# laravel, How to add conditions to function __construct()

Tags: php, laravel

How can I add some conditions to function __construct(), such as if middleware is admin or the current user id equal to this post user_id,
I have posts created by users so the only ones who can edit are the one who created this post or the admin
I tried the code below, so role_id=4 means this is an admin,

thank you in advance

```
public function __construct($post_number)
{
   $posts=Post::where('post_number',$post_number)->first();
  where(Auth::User()->id==$posts->user_id)OR (Auth::User()->role_id==4);
}
```

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: I suggest you look into [Authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization)

Comment: If this is a controller constructor (you dont say) then the Auth::user() is not initialised when the constructors are called. You have to wrap the code in a middleware callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel when method. Now your code should look like this.

```
public function __construct($post_number)
{
   $posts=Post::where('post_number',$post_number)->first();

   if($posts->user_id == auth()->user()->id || auth()->user()->role_id == 4) {
       //cann edit the post
   } else {
        //cannot edit the post
        return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Im getting the error Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $post_number ]] in class App\Http\Controllers\EditPostController

Comment: in the post I have a link so from route the link something like this Route::get('/manage_post/{post_number}', 'EditPostController@EditPost')->name('post.modify');

Comment: and you want to do your condition in construct method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your middleware then simply added into your constructor of your controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->middleware('your_custom_middleware');
}
```

Also in this way you can add except method.

for more information click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a [dedicated policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-policies) class which makes the code quite expressive about your intentions.

so first run `php artisan make:policy PostPolicy`. Then open your Policy class and update it as follow,

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Post;

class PostPolicy
{

    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        // May be define isAdmin() on user class ??
        return $user->role_id==4 || $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

once the policy is created then you can register it in your `AuthService provider` as

```
protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];
```

By the way also give a quick read to [Policy Auto Discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#registering-policies)

Once thats done, this is what you can do then,

```
public function __construct($post_number)
{
   $posts=Post::where('post_number',$post_number)->first();

   $this->authorize('update', PostPolicy::class);
}
```